# There seems to be a bug in searching by tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

If I type in

```
[textboxlist]
```

in the search on Stack Overflow, it gives me 0 results. But if I search by:

```
textboxlist
```

I see a number of questions that have this tag on them. Seems like something is broken with the tag search feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on the **featured** or **faq** tabs? When searching for a tag or combination of tags only, you're redirected to the tag page, the tab you're on is remember from the last tab page you browsed.

If you're on the featured (bounty) tab though, there may be no questions currently with a bounty *that matched the tags you're searching for*.  However, aside from **featured**/**faq**, all of the *other* tabs (newest, votes, active) should have questions, unanswered will have some if any match that criteria as well.

I currently see 9 questions tagged [textboxlist](/questions/tagged/textboxlist) (none with a bounty) on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textboxlist

---

*Update:* In the build tonight, to make things clearer, new messages will appear on the **FAQ** and **Unanswered** tags when no questions show up (since there may be questions, but none matching the criteria for *those* tabs):

- > You are on the FAQ tab.
  >   There are no frequently asked questions at the moment.
  >   **Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?**
- > You are on the Unanswered tab.
  >   There are no unanswered questions at the moment.
  >   **Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?**

Comment: @Nick Craver - still very misleading.  I am on the main page, stackoverflow.com and then i search for this tag and in the right it says "O questions tagged" (it takes me to the FAQ tab).  when i change the tab to "newest" it now shows "9 questions tagged".  should it show 9 always ??

Comment: @ooo - We respect the tab you left the page on, though when coming from search I do agree it can be misleading if you *don't* intend to stay on the tab.  On the flip side, should a search redirect change your saved tab preference?  We'll discuss this today and see if a change in behavior makes the most sense here.

Comment: @Nick Craver -  i was not previously on the FAQ tab.  In fact this tab is not even shown on the previous view so i don't think your comment is accurate. let me know if i am unclear. my point is that, even on the FAQ tab, it should still show 9 questions instead of 0. I understand that featured wouldn't

Comment: @ooo - If those questions aren't "frequently asked", they won't appear on the faq tab.  Think of it this way: they are the *most* frequently asked, but they must meet the "frequently" criteria before being shown there.

Comment: @Nick Craver - i guess i see what you are saying.  to be more explicit, you could show both # of frequent out of total # of items tagged. in this case it would show something like (O frequent out of 9 total tagged questions).  no ambiguity at this point.

Comment: @ooo - We've made the behavior consistent for all these "could have no results" tabs, when there's the case of no questions matching the criteria for that tab, we'll display the messages added in the above answer...like were already there for "featured".

Comment: @Nick Craver - sounds good.  i think the root issue is around the FAQ tab as there is no concrete definition of FAQ.  Unanswered is clear and thus no issue.